# "listen" notification area icon is somehow green-ish

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook, notification-area

I installed the beautiful application "Listen" this morning, however when I started it, its applet within the indicator menue was somehow shown green-ish.
My first thought was that well, maybe the png is indeed with a green background (even though that wouldn't make sense). But I checked all the icons in `/usr/share/listen/img/`, and as far as I can tell, they're all with a transparent background.

I'm running 10.04.1 Netbook Remix on a Asus Eeepc 1002HA

Comment: Is that really an indicator or just part of the system tray?

Comment: @Nick HS: Yep, you're right, it's indeed a system tray icon (see accepted answer). Damn menue bar.. Some application icons are part of the indicator panel, and some aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tray icon (it is not an application indicator) is supposed to be transparent.
There is a bug report on this: https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/listen/+bug/562621.